# I can't merge public and private keys in one PFX file

Tags: ssl, openssl, key, private, public

I got certificate for domain from www.startssl.com. I downloaded a copy of this cert and saved it as .p12 file.

Then using windows console, I exported certificate including private key to .pfx file, and after that I selected option "without private key", and exported public key to .cer file (using Base-64 algorythm).

Next, I converted .pfx to .pem file using OpenSSL.  Now I've got two files - public and private key, and they can be both opened by notepad.

SSL on my domain can be established only by pasting two strings - public and private key. I done it and it didn't work - there was a warning saying that privat key is wrong. So I tried to merge both keys in startssl tool "Create PKCS#12 (PFX) File" - an error again. The same when I used OpenSSL to get pfx.

Why one p.12 file can be split into - finally - two keys, but after that they can't be merged again into one file?

What did I do wrong?
I'm going mad with it.

Many thanks for any help

Comment: What are the exact headers in your files?  They should say something like, "Begin Certificate" or "Begin Private Key".  I suspect that when you converted the pfx to pem in OpenSSL, the output file actually contains 2 sections, one for a certificate, and one for a private key.  Also, when you say that you exported the public key to a .cer file, you probably exported an X509 certificate, which contains the public key, but is not just a public key.  If you need only the public key, you can use OpenSSL to extract the public key from the X509 certificate.

Answer (score 1):

p12 and pfx are actually same pkcs#12 format. usually, they don't just contain a private and a public keys, but also intermediate/root certificates. you can check this links out:
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html
http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.3/cxf_security/i298613.html